# pointing eclipse to correct jar version in mvn repo

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

our maven repo currently has two versions of mockito, both versions are being pulled in as dependencies to other jars, and each is used in a different child project.  Our integration-tests, which are a separate project, use a different version then the unit tests used by our core application.

The mockito versions have changed the signature of a method, making them not backwards computable.  Due to the jars that each mockito version is dependent on it isn't easy for me to reconfigure maven to use only one version of mockito for each project.

When I run maven directly, from eclipse or command line, this is not an issue, the correct mockito version is used for each project based off of the pom file.  However, when I try to run our unit tests in eclipse I am getting a NoSuchMethodError, which seems to be due to eclipse using the incorrect mockito version.  Is there a way to ensure my junit tests use the version of version of mockito I want, aka the one specified in the pom file?

Comment: can you provide an example from the project pom.xml files?  The dependency on mockito should have a <scope> of 'test' where ever it is used.  This should prevent the project on which you're running the test from being affected by the version used by other projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you should do is declaring mockito as a direct dependency of the modules that use it and not rely on it being drawn in through a transitive dependency. Maven/Eclipse/m2e should [first use the version that is declared locally](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Transitive_Dependencies).

If that fails to resolve the problem, in my experience, it can help reordering the dependencies in the POM and checking the *Maven Dependencies*  container in the project explorer or the *Dependency Hierarchy* tab in the POM editor afterwards to see if the right version is now used. Typically trying to move the problematic dependency either to the first position in the dependency list or to the last position resolves the problem.

Another (possibly additional) option is to add an exclude to that dependency which draws in the "wrong" version of mockito. Again, check the *Dependency Hierarchy* tab to see where the dependencies are coming from.

Finally, you should save yourself headaches and set up a project-wide [dependency management](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Management) that covers the unit tests in your application as well as the integration tests.

Good luck ;)

Answer (score -1):

In Eclipse, go to your run configuration for your unit test. There is a "Classpath" tab there. You should be able to modify your classpath there to use the proper version of the jar.

Comment: That will not work for Maven-managed dependencies - they are all inside a "container" called "Maven Dependencies" and cannot be changed individually.